# How to redeem an invitation with Microsoft Graph?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I have existed users in my DB with the email already validated.
I would like to invite them as Guest to our Azure Active Directory to make them able to chat on teams using Azure Communication Services.

```
        var invitation = new Invitation
        {
            InvitedUserEmailAddress = userModel.Email,
            InvitedUser = new User
            {
                GivenName = userModel.Firstname,
                Surname = userModel.Lastname,
                DisplayName = $"{userModel.Firstname} {userModel.Lastname}",
                Mail = userModel.Email,
                UserType = "Guest", // Member
                OtherMails = new List<string> { userModel.Email },
                Identities = new List<ObjectIdentity>
        {
            new ObjectIdentity
            {
                SignInType = "emailAddress",
                Issuer = "Unknow",
                IssuerAssignedId = userModel.Email
            },
        },
                PasswordPolicies = "DisablePasswordExpiration"
            },
            SendInvitationMessage = false,
            InviteRedirectUrl = redirectUrl.ToString(),
            InvitedUserType = "guest" // default is guest,member
        };
        var invite = await Client.Invitations.PostAsync(invitation);
```

First I thought that calling the redeemUrl returned by Microsoft could work:

```
        await _httpClient.GetAsync(invite.InviteRedeemUrl)
```

I have a 200 code returned, but the use is still in pending status.

How can I redeem the invitation by code using Microsoft Graph?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/invitation?view=graph-rest-1.0), there is no API to perform the redemption process.

The invited user has to go through the **interactive** redemption process in a browser. Calling `inviteRedeemUrl` through `HttpClient` has no effect on the redemption process. The invited user has to sign-in and authenticate.

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/cross-tenant-access-overview#automatic-redemption-setting), automatic redemption is currently in preview, so I don't expect that Graph API will support it soon.